# Are the meets of the set of 2-adic numbers that terminate in $\overline{01}_2$ **not quite** homeomorphic to the free group on two elements?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, terminology, products

I think the set $X$ of 2-adic numbers that terminate in $\overline{01}_2$ is super-close to homeomorphic to the free group on two elements, but not quite.  Can you help me characterise "not quite"?

Here's the following argument:

The labelled, infinite, binary **rooted** (at $-\frac13$) tree in which $\{2x,2x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\}$ are the children of $x$ is a cover of the set $X$.

$x\mapsto 2x$ is a homeomorphism.

$x\mapsto 2x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ is a homeomorphism.

I think the binary rooted tree can be thought of as homeomorphic to the free monoid on two elements with concatenation as the operation.  Each of the above functions represents one of the generators.

The composition of the two is therefore a homeomorphism.

I think each homeomorphism constitutes an idempotent operation which orientates the the graph to either left-handed or right-handed - correct?

I think the composition of the two homeomorphisms, maps $-\frac13\to-\frac13$

Since $-\frac13$ is a parent of itself, therefore the infinite, binary **unrooted** tree also represents $X$ (and hence the two functions above being homeomorphisms rather than just semihomeomorphisms).

Now the tree is unrooted, every binary string has an inverse.  Except, I don't quite think it does **if I consider handedness of the graph**.  How do I characterise this?

Comment: I can't parse "the set $X$ of 2-adic numbers that converge to $\overline{01}_2$"

Comment: When you talk about homeomorphisms, you need to have a topology on the free monoid (respectively on the free group) on the binary alphabet. What is this topology?

Comment: @reuns $\frac13\Bbb Z$ written as 2-adic numbers. Sorry, I should probably have put that *terminate* in, or that converge there on truncation. You can take your pick whether you include those divided by $2^i:i\in\Bbb N$ as $x\mapsto x/2$ is a self-similar map.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin the visualisation I'm using is the binary rooted or unrooted tree (depending whether you include the self-similar map $-\frac13\to-\frac14$. I think this technically gives it the graph topology.  But since it's labelled with elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ it also has the 2-adic topology, and the "congruence" I'm looking for at $-\frac13\mapsto -\frac13$ is represented in both.

Comment: I don't understand what is "the set $X$".

Comment: @reuns let the 2-adic integers be the set $\Bbb Z_2=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2^kx_k):x_k\in\{0,1\}\right\}$.  Then $X$ is the subset of $\Bbb Z_2$ for which there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $k>m$ it is true that $x_k\neq x_{k+1}$.

Comment: So $X=\{ a-2^b/3 \in \Bbb{Z}_2, a,b\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\}$, whence it is unclear what you mean with a free group over 2 elements

Comment: @reuns the reader isn't meant to assume this is standard additve or multiplicative group. I'm looking at the meet/join relationships of its labelled, infinite, binary rooted tree as operations.